# Onchange Functon in odoo: TypeError: on_change_bill_id() takes at least 7 arguments (6 given)

Tags: odoo

Please i am trying to use an onchange function.
here is the python:

```
def on_change_bill_id(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, account_id, invoice_mode, context=None):
    print ('------------------------Facturation on change--------------------')
var = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
print ('account = ' ) 
print  account_id
print ('partner =' ) 
print  partner_id
    res = {'value':{
                    'invoice_line': self.get_inputs2(cr, uid, ids, partner_id, account_id, invoice_mode, context=context),
                   }
          }
    print ('-------------------Onchange-----------------------')
    return res
```

And my xml:

```
 <field name="date_end" on_change="on_change_bill_id(partner_id, account_id, invoice_mode)"/>
```

The problem is when i use just:

```
<field name="date_end" on_change="on_change_bill_id(partner_id, account_id)"/>
```

everything works fine and when when i add invoice_mode i got:
**TypeError: on_change_bill_id() takes at least 7 arguments (6 given)**
Please help me understand.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: With which model you are working ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with parameters. We need to pass value/variable based on .xml side passes. If we pass two variables than in .py side we must have only two variables.

For Example, If we use this

```
<field name="date_end" on_change="on_change_bill_id(partner_id, account_id, invoice_mode)"/>
```

Than .py side must be catch 3 variable.

```
def on_change_bill_id(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, account_id, invoice_mode, context=None):
     #here is your code logic
```

If you change xml side and pass two variable than we must catch same in .py side.

For Example

```
<field name="date_end" on_change="on_change_bill_id(partner_id, account_id)"/>
```

Than .py side method will look like

```
def on_change_bill_id(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, account_id, context=None):
     #here is your code logic
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but sir thats what i have done exactly and i got the error: 
TypeError: on_change_bill_id() takes at least 7 arguments (6 given)

Comment: nope it will not give you error any more if you upgrade your module properly.

Comment: I have upgraded my module many times but nothing happens. I get this error

Comment: what if i am unable to upgrade the module. I press upgrade many times and i et the same error. Please who can help

Comment: you need to first stop the server and restart it and than you need to upgrade your module. Please check out twice your addons path, and make sure you are changing the right one files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But i have stopped the server, restarted it and chosen the suitable module but nothing happen. And when i have created a new module with the same code there no error??!! SO hat could be the source??!

Comment: you need to checkout addons path in *openerp-server.conf* file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try by updating this line,

```
<field name="date_end" on_change="on_change_bill_id(partner_id, account_id, invoice_mode, context)"/>
```